# How to get recent build TFS programmatically?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, tfs

Ok i am new to TFS. I want to get the recent build pro grammatically using c# code. i have seen other post about this, they did this way

```
var buildDefinitions = buildServer.QueryBuildDefinitions("Project_name").Where(bd=>bd.DateCreated.Date>=DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date);
```

But I need to get an example of this image click [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q0NQ9.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you know, the method returns [`IBuildDefinition`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.teamfoundation.build.client.ibuilddefinition(v=vs.120).aspx)s. And since you seem to be wanting to find them by name, you could do something like:

```
var buildDefinitions = buildServer
    .QueryBuildDefinitions("Project_name")
    .Where(bd => bd.Name == yourBuildName);
```